# Is the CurrentRoleInstance.id permanent in deployed apps?

Tags: azure

I have a brief and simple question i think.. in the emulator the role id changes in every run. What about in a real azure deployment? After a restart of the vm does the role gets the same id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the id for the deployed instances in the cloud, you'll find that they are always named in this fasion: **`[RoleName]_IN_[XXX]`** where XXX is a number depending on the number of instances deployed. So to answer your question, since the pattern for naming the instance is the same, I would say you'll get the same id. It's a different question if the VM represented by that instance id would be the same. There're 3 scenarios to cover:

1. A role instance is rebooted: If you reboot a particular instance, my guess is you will get the same instance id.
2. A role instance goes down: Though we don't really have an option of killing a specific instance thus we can't really test it, if a particular instance goes down and Azure stands up a new instance for you for that instance you would get the same instance id.
3. New deployment: If you do a brand new deployment (assuming with the same number of instances), you'll get the same deployment ids but the VM will be entirely different.

Comment: Gaurav Mantri, thank you for your reply. So only the instance count changes (cause in emulator both name and instance count changes). Trying to design a recovery mechanism and I am depending on the id of the role. I can deal with the change of only the count number but not with name as in the emulator.

Comment: That's correct. The pattern for naming the instance in the cloud is the one I mentioned above.